# D FlipFlop sequence generator for the sequence 1101011 does not generate results

Tags: verilog, register-transfer-level, digital-design

I have created a module for DFlipFlop in `DFF` module and instantiated 4 of them in `seqgen` module. I am not able to generate results. Can you please help me where I am going wrong?

```
module DFF(input d, input rstn, input clk, output reg q);

    always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn)
        if(!rstn)
            q <= 0;
        else
            q <= d;
endmodule

module seqgen();
    wire q1=1'b1,q2=1'b1,q3=1'b1,q4=1'b0;
    wire da=1'b1;
    reg clk = 1'b0,rstn  = 1;
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    assign da = ~q1|~q2|~q4;
    DFF dffa(da,rstn,clk,q1);
    DFF dffb(q1,rstn,clk,q2);
    DFF dffc(q2,rstn,clk,q3);
    DFF dffd(q3,rstn,clk,q4);
endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of problems.

The outputs of your `DFF` modules are being driven from within the `DFF` module and from within the `seqgen` module due to the continuous `wire`  assignment.  You should not assign a value to the `wire`.  This causes contention which is one source of the unknown values (`x`) on the outputs.  In the case of `da`, you have 2 continuous assignments, but you should only have 1.

Also, you should assert the reset at time 0, wait for a delay, then deassert the reset.  This is another source of the unknowns.  Since it is an active-low reset, set it to 0, then after a delay, set it to 1.

This code gets rid of the unknown signals for me.

```
module seqgen();
    wire q1,q2,q3,q4;
    wire da;
    reg clk = 1'b0, rstn = 0;
    initial #25 rstn=1;
    always #10 clk = ~clk;
    assign da = ~q1|~q2|~q4;
    DFF dffa(da,rstn,clk,q1);
    DFF dffb(q1,rstn,clk,q2);
    DFF dffc(q2,rstn,clk,q3);
    DFF dffd(q3,rstn,clk,q4);
endmodule
```